# How do I make a Typed Value for the actual color of an entity in Autocad .NET

Tags: c#, autocad, autocad-plugin, autocad-scripts

I'm trying to select by color using the typed value below in a selection filter:

```
new TypedValue((int)DxfCode.Color, myColor)
```

The problem with this is that some entities have the color values 'byblock' or 'bylayer'. Is there a way to filter on the actual color value being displayed on screen?

Answer (score 0):

Does this [case](https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/net/typedvalue-filter-by-color-with-bylayer/td-p/5205195) answer your question?

Find out the layers with the target color=> Filter on layers